# Internal Server Error when using django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis in settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis

## I always got Internal Server Error when I use postgis in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         #'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'geodb',
         'USER': 'postgres',
    }
}
```

### But it works if I use the sqlite3:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I am using python3.6, django 1.11.4, postgis postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.3 on Centos 7.

Spent the whole day to search for a solution but not able to find any. Appreciate it for any help.

Comment: what does the stack traceback say? please post it

Comment: did you install psycopg2? `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: I did install psycopg2 using the following command. sudo pip3.6 install psycopg2

Comment: I am able to import it:

`Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 22:59:34)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> exit()`

Comment: Here is traceback log:
**
Error_log:
   
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 2, in <module>
        from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import (
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
    ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg2
**

Comment: Verified it psycopg2 was installed:
**
$ yum list |grep psycopg2
python-psycopg2.x86_64                   2.5.1-3.el7                    base
python-psycopg2-debug.x86_64             2.5.1-3.el7                    base
python-psycopg2-doc.x86_64               2.5.1-3.el7                    base
python36u-psycopg2.x86_64                2.7.3-1.ius.centos7            ius
python36u-psycopg2-debuginfo.x86_64      2.7.3-1.ius.centos7            ius
**